# why does object address of s3 gets printed?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,m1,m2):
        self.mrks1= m1
        self.mrks2 = m2
    def __add__(self,other)
        r1 = self.mrks1 +other.mrks1
        r2 = self.mrks2 + other.mrks2
s = A(r1,r2) 
return s

a1 = A(1,2)
a2 = A(2,3)
s3 = s1+s2
print(s3)
```

whis object address of s3 gets printed istead of addition of objects

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there, i'll explain why you don't get the expected output.

You realize that when you sum two objects with +, internally the **sum** method is called.

Well, when you print an object, is the same but with the **str** method!!

```
class A:
def __init__(self,m1,m2):
    self.mrks1= m1
    self.mrks2 = m2
def __add__(self,other):
    r1 = self.mrks1 +other.mrks1
    r2 = self.mrks2 + other.mrks2
    self.mrks1= r1
    self.mrks2 = r2
    s = A(r1,r2) 
    return s
def __str__(self):
    return "Values are " + str(self.mrks1) + ' ' + str(self.mrks2)


s1 = A(1,2)
s2 = A(2,3)
s3 = s1+s2
print(s3)
```

if you print without a __ str __ method an object, what is printing is the method default for objects! Thus printing the address of the objecct, you need to override this, by declaring __ str __

Comment: @Dharman thanks for clearing the doubt but when i use this method ,                     
 class A:
def __init__(self,m1,m2):
    self.mrks1= m1
    self.mrks2 = m2
def __add__(self,other):
 return self.mrks1+ other.mrks1 , self.mrks2 + other.mrks2 


s1 = A(1,2)
s2 = A(2,3)
s3 = s1+s2
print(s3)    then i get direct O/P as (3,3) i.e addition of s1 and s2